# XSLT-FO for-each

Tags: xml, apache, xslt, apache-fop

This is my xml:

```
<OrdersSchedulePDFView>
 <OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow>
   <Locations>
     <LocName>Text1</LocName>
     <LocName>Text2</LocName>         
   </Locations>
 </OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow>     
</OrdersSchedulePDFView>
```

And this is fragment from my xslt-fo file:

```
<xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFView">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">        
        <xsl:for-each select="./OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow">        
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all">            
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">                       
                    <xsl:for-each select="Locations">                   
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>                  
                    </xsl:for-each>                             
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Locations">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="LocName"/></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But in PDF I have only one LocName. How can I get all LocName elements?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="LocName"/>` gets the value of only the first `LocName` (in XSLT 1.0). To get them all, you need to use `<xsl:for-each select="LocName">`. Or apply templates to them, and add a corresponding template. --- BTW, you do **not** need to use `<xsl:for-each select="Locations">` in order to apply the template matching `Locations`. Just say `<xsl:apply-templates select="Locations"/>`.

Comment: Finally, I figured this out.

<fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates select="Locations"/></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
<xsl:template match="Locations">
 <xsl:for-each select="./LocName">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
 </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update: since apparently you have no code to add for a `Locations` element, you could shorten your code by changing:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Locations"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Locations/LocName"/>
```

and then doing:

```
<xsl:template match="LocName"> 
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial"> 
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:inline> 
    </fo:block> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct code for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">   
<xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFView">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">        
        <xsl:for-each select="./OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow">        
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all">            
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" background-color="black" color="white" padding="2pt" font-family="Arial">Stores</fo:block>
                    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates select="Locations"/></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>                             
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Locations">
    <xsl:for-each select="./LocName">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: DId this code work for you. I am trying to achieve something similar but it just doesn't work for me. how exactly is your data structure